# Instantly shut down or set log out for users

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP .NET MVC 2.0 WebApplication, and i need to have a button named "Shut down" or "Block all". It should log out all users, or something like this (mb shut down server).

Is it possible? Thx.

Comment: What would you want those users to see when this occurs? I think there's confusion about the technical aspect of what you're asking for, but sounds like you want a simple blocking of the web site.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to take your site offline? `App_offline.htm` would probably be best - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Forms Authentication unless you track your users with some Session it would be impossible to log users out. Authenticated users are tracked by cookies and even if you restart the application domain using the `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` method client browsers still have the authentication cookies and users will be automatically logged in on subsequent requests. But if you store some user specific information in the session when you restart the application domain this information would be deleted and you would know that the user should no longer be authenticated as it has no associated session data.

Comment: May be is it possible to make something with SQL server connection or something else? =\

Comment: Now i'm looking for HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdown

Comment: @user568262, no matter what you do, users have cookies in their browsers and unless you track them on the server (like for example in the session) you simply won't be able to log them out, so this is where I would recommend focusing your efforts on.

Comment: Or creating App_Offline.htm in root :) looks like very good and simple solution, if i could do it in code.

Comment: @user568262, yes but this brings your entire site down. It's almost like plugging the Ethernet cable out from your server :-) It doesn't log out the users. Once you remove this file users that have their cookies (if not expires) could be logged back in.

Comment: @user568262, if you don't track that a user is authenticated **on the server** (session, database, ...) you can't do much to prevent this from happening, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to set a flag somewhere that indicates this has happened. Then have an action filter on all of your controllers that checks for this flag. If it is set, log the user out (this depends on what sort of authentication you are using) and optionally redirect them to a page that explains what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about this. Authentification mode=forms.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the end i decided to make 2 ways in one solution. At first, it should create App_offline.htm (just for beautifull) page in wwwroot directory and block all users. When page would be removed, 2 ways:

1. Cookie expired
2. Opened web page, but after first
   click, user would be redirected to
   /Account/LogOn

After administrator unblock users, they could login. Don't know what about other, for me its not so bad issue. Thx all.

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).IsLockedOut)
        {
            IFormsAuthenticationService FormsService = new FormsAuthenticationService();
            FormsService.SignOut();
        }
        // The action filter logic.
    }
}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult ShutDown()
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\iMagazin\\App_offline.htm");
    sw.Close();
    _dataManager.Users.BlockAll();
    return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
}
```

Apply ActionFilter to Controller

```
[SUPNew.Models.Extansions.LogActionFilter]
public class SuperadministratorController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```